# How to move up even the UINavigation bar up along with the UITableView when a UITextField in its cell is in editing mode?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uinavigationbar

This is the hierarchy:

`UITableViewController`
contains `UINavigationBar` & `UITableView`.
`UITableView`'s cell has `UITextField`s.
When editing the textField, to accommodate the keyboard, the whole table moves up, however the `UINavigationBar` still remains at the top position.
How to move the navigationBar along with the table when the textFields are in editing mode.
Currently there is no code required to move the table up when a textfield in one of its cell is in editing mode.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `navigationController?.hidesBarsWhenKeyboardAppears = true` in the viewcontroller to hide the navigationBar toolbar. According to the documentation the bars will remain hidden when the keyboard dismisses, but a tap in the content area will show them.

Comment: Thank you @laxmankhanal for an elegant solution! It worked well for my requirements.